# Get Sunday Of Given Start Date And Saturday Of End Date

Tags: vb.net

I want to change my starting date to Sunday of the `StartDate` and `EndDate` to Saturday of EndDate.Suppose my `StartDate` is 23-04-2014,it will become 20-04-2013 and my `EndDate` is 13-05-2014,it will become 17-05-2014.How can i achieve this is vb.net.In short what I want is to convert my `StartDate` to Sunday of given date week and `EndDate` to Saturday of given date week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will these work for your purposes?

```
Function GetPreviousSunday(fromDate As Date) As Date
    Return fromDate.AddDays(0 - fromDate.DayOfWeek)
End Function

Function GetNextSaturday(fromDate As Date) As Date
    Return fromDate.AddDays(6 - fromDate.DayOfWeek)
End Function
```

You could even turn it into one function:

```
Function GetRelativeWeekdayDate(fromDate As Date, relativeToWeekdayNum As Integer) As Date
    Return fromDate.AddDays(relativeToWeekdayNum - fromDate.DayOfWeek)
End Function
```

Which you would call like this for Sunday: `GetRelativeWeekdayDate(StartDate, 0)` and this for Saturday: `GetRelativeWeekdayDate(EndDate, 6)`.